# php date() function displaying wrong time

Tags: php, wordpress, date, timezone

I'm building a site with wordpress, and when I use the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function on an otherwise empty file, it shows the right date.  However, if I use it in a file that includes other wordpress files, the time is displayed as GMT time, so the date is off.

If anyone can figure out how I can use date function without interruption from the wordpress methods, I'd appreciated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Dont use word press so im not sure but it sounds like there is a setting in wp that is applied using `date_default_timezone_set()`. Its probably configured to GMT to allow for easy calculation of user preferences from within WP. I would look to see if this is configurable in WP, or do the math youself using the necessary functions and/or objects.

Answer (score 3):

The Wordpress template tag `the_time` displays according to your Wordpress defaults: [Template Tags/the time « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time). date() may get over written by Wordpress. But you can look at `the_time` usage and code samples to change the output more to what you need: [Formatting Date and Time « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)

Answer (score 3):

Try using the date_i18n() function available in Wordpress, I had a similar problem and used that function rather than date(). Check out the WP docs - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n